# Constructing Galois Extensions of Desired Degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Suppose that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian Galois extension with Galois group $H$. Let $m= |H|=[K \colon \mathbb{Q}]$. Given an abelian group $G$ with $H \leq G$ and $|G|=km$, is it possible to find an extension $L/K/\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G$? That is, given an abelian Galois extension, is it possible to extend this to another Galois field of desired degree so that the original Galois group is a specified subgroup?

For example, if $[K \colon \mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $G= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, one can just take the $L$ to be the compositum of $K$ and another degree 2 extension.

But is this sort of idea always possible for 'nice' extensions, i.e. abelian Galois extensions? It is always easy to create an extension $L$ of degree $km$ or usually not difficult create a Galois field extension having $H$ as a subgroup, but to do both has proved a difficult task.

Comment: I don't think your question is phrased correctly. If $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian Galois extension with Galois group $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the corresponding fixed field, say $K$, of $H$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. $L/K$ is Galois regardless of whether the extension is abelian or not. We then have $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) = G/H$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K) = H$. So if $|G| = km $ and $|H|=m$, then $K/F$ is an extension of degree $k$ and $L/K$ is of degree $m$.

Comment: Edit: I meant $K/\mathbb{Q}$ and not $K/F$.

Comment: @ParthivBasu Yes, I did incorrectly state the degrees in the $|G|=km$ because of the inclusion-reversing nature of the correspondence. But as to the rest, yes, $K$ is Galois because $L$ is but the content is that you start with $K$ and you want to extend to an abelian Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ of a desired degree with $H \leq G$ in a specified way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not always. This is the *extension problem*. As an example, consider $\Bbb Q(i)/\Bbb Q$.
There is no extension $L/\Bbb Q(i)$ such that $L/\Bbb Q$ is Galois over $\Bbb Q$
with cyclic Galois group of order $4$.

To see this, observe that complex conjugation must induce an
order two automorphism of $L$, so must be the square of the generator. But $\Bbb Q(i)$ is the fixed field of the square of the generator (by the Galois correspondence) but its elements are not fixed by complex conjugation.

Comment: Thanks! The *extension problem* has never crossed my path so I was not aware. Do you know where I could find more or even for which types of fields this does not work for, especially in low degree extensions like a fixed cubic or quintic Galois field or given a Galois groups like $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.